# OnClick react Button to show table

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am trying to click a react Button, and display a table. The Button should return a table but when i click on it but it returns nothing. Anyone can help? Much appreciate!

my function

```
    const getSchedule = () => {
   
    return (
        <div>
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Schedule Id</th>
                        <th>Trainer Id</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Start Time</th>
                        <th>End Time</th>
                        <th>Action</th>

                    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {/* {schedule.map(render_schedule)}  */}

                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    )

}
```

my Button:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let check=false
const getSchedule = () => {
    check=True
};
```

In your main function return use somethin like this to display your table if check is True ( check is initialized False and clicking the button set it to True ):

```
{check && <div>..your table code here </div>}
```

Your onClick handler stays the same:

<`button onClick={getSchedule}>show table</button>`

Comment: I have tried your ans, but it does not work

Comment: The problem is that you are not returning anything to the DOM. can you please explain where do you want you table to appear in your page. To check if your onClick handler works, try and change the return of getSchedule to a simple "console.log('ok')".

Comment: I wish to display the table below the button and the onClick handler works

Comment: Ok then you can add the code that i just commented ( {check && <dvi...) under your button and it should work fine. ( make sure to initialize check and getSchedule before your return

Comment: And if you want you button to  toggle the table ( hide and display ) you can set : check = !check , inside your getSchedule.

Answer (score 1):

This is because even though you are returning your table div the page react is not re-rendering the page.

React re-renders page only when state changes

Assuming you want to show the table below your button you can do this:-

```
<Button onClick={()=>getSchedule()}>Search Schedule</Button>
<div>{this.state.schedule}</div>
```

create a schedule in state

```
constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = { schedule:[]};
    }
```

and not finally in your getSchedule you need to assign all the HTML thing to schedule using setState()

```
 const getSchedule = () => {
   let newSchedule = [];
   newSchedule.push(<div><Table>.......</div>);
   this.setState({schedule:newSchedule});
}
```

here initially this.state.schedule will be empty so nothing is rendered, but when we update schedule and setState it will rerender the page but now this.state.schedule will have your table HTML